# One edit to record trigger PBR multiple times?

Tags: workflow, process-builder

Will a PBR be triggered multiple times if multiple qualifying changes occur in a single transaction? For example:

- PBR triggers off an edit to a Contact
- First criteria is "First Name IS NULL false"
- Second criteria is "Last Name IS NULL false"
- Each criteria has a different set of actions

If I open a Contact that has no First Name or Last Name, then add values to them both at the same time and save it, will the PBR fire twice -- once for each criteria -- or will it only fire once and only run through the first choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that circumstance, you're not looking at [Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) and potential recursion during a transaction, but looking rather at how Process Builder evaluates its criteria.

The process itself will fire only once in the situation you described. However, you can configure whether the individual criteria nodes, when they execute, result in ending the process execution or continuing to evaluate the next criterion node and potentially executing its associated actions.

[image: Process Builder screenshot]

Configure this by clicking the "Stop" icon at the end of the pipeline for one criterion, and choosing to continue to evaluate the next criterion.

Remember, though, that this all takes place in *one* Process Builder execution. It is possible to invoke the process itself twice in a transaction, if a record update results in further updates to that record, for example.

A final note: `Contact.LastName` is a required field. It'll never be `null`.

#### Reference

- [Execute Actions on More Than One Criteria](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_next_criteria.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks for the insight -- and sorry for the bad example re: Last Name, that's not the actual field in question, just the first ones that came to mind when trying to explain.